# Anybody know story behind pgFoundry (PostgreSQL project site) downtime?

Tags: postgresql

pgFoundry site's been unreachable 2 days and counting....

I have googled up some ominous messages from the Spring about it eventually closing, but I had never seen any notice on the site to say that was imminent.

Any inside scoop?

Comment: [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905052215/http://pgfoundry.org/) shows the latest snapshot has no news about this.

Comment: pgFoundry has been shutdown. I got an email about this but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: @Colin'tHart http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.pgbouncer.general/1248 ? http://postgresql.nabble.com/Shutting-down-the-pgfoundry-project-td5834990.html? Both of those *probably* refer to projects moving away from it, not the site its self, but it's hard to be sure for the former.

Comment: @CraigRinger If I remember correctly, it was an email from Marc Fournier to say that it would be shutdown and a few days later an unsubscribe confirmation from a pgFoundry announce list. And now the site is gone, so I think it's fair to assume it's gone for good.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: It's back. No explanation I've seen.

---

Pgfoundry is maintained outside the PostgreSQL infrastructure team's jurisdiction. It's a 3rd party site, and it hasn't seen a great deal of attention lately. Most projects on pgfoundry have moved to GitHub or git.postgresql.org.

If there's a particular project still on PgFoundry that you use, please contact its maintainers and ask them to relocate to git.postgresql.org or github.

If you're unable to reach them after a few weeks consider adopting the project and re-hosting it; just be prepared to hand hosting back over if the original maintainers reappear.

It was originally run by Marc Fournier. I'm not sure if he still runs it. You could ask on the pgsql-www mailing list for more information.

*(Note that while I contribute to PostgreSQL, I am not a member of the infrastructure team, core team, or a committer. I do not speak for the project, or for my employer.)*

Comment: Just received from Marc Fournier: “not closing, will look at when i get home ... sorry for delay”

Comment: @ChapmanFlack your comment seems incomplete